# AS3 Accessing movieclip on stage from multiple classes

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class

I have a fla file with a movieclip on the stage that is called "ding".

I have a Main.as file with the following code (in here i can trace ding.x):

```
package { 

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

public class Main extends MovieClip{
    public static var _goviral:goviral;

    public function Main() {
        createPlayer();
    }

    public function createPlayer():void{

        _goviral = new goviral();

        trace(ding.x);
    }

}
}
```

I also have a goviral.as with the following code (here i cannot trace ding.x):

```
package { 

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import Main;

public class goviral extends MovieClip{

    public var main:Main;


    public function goviral(){
        main = new Main();
        trace(ding.x);
    }
}
}
```

How can i trace movieclips from the goviral.as class? I have been banging my head against the wall to get this to work. Please help me!

tnx!

Comment: won't this cause an infinite loop? your main creates a new goviral object in its constructor, while the goviral Constructor creates a Main Object in its own constructor, thus creating a new goviral Object, which creates a new Main Object etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @DodgerThud pointed out, you need to fix the infinite loop issue first.
You can pass ding into the constructor of goviral so it has it's own reference to it:

```
package { 

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

public class Main extends MovieClip{
    public static var _goviral:goviral;

    public function Main() {
        createPlayer();
    }

    public function createPlayer():void{

        _goviral = new goviral(ding);
    }

}
}
```

You should not instantiate Main again.

```
package { 

import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class goviral extends MovieClip{    

    public function goviral(ding:MovieClip){
        trace(ding.x);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Tnx, but this is not working for me. i get the following error: Error: Error #2136: The SWF file file:///C|/Users/mnobe%5F000/Desktop/Class%20test/test.swf contains invalid data.

Comment: As @DodgerThud pointed out, this will not work because of the inifinite loop. I will change my answer to fix your code.